# PHP continue loop unless value is found or reach the end of array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My data returned from an API looks like this (`$response`):

```
{
    "data": {
        "connections": [
            {
                "source": 1
            },
            {
                "source": 6
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, then I do this:

```
$array = json_decode( $response, true );
$results = $array['data']['connections']; 
foreach($results as $member) 
{
    if  ($member['source'] == 6)
    {
        function1();//run this function
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        //what goes here? //reloop                   
    }
}
```

So, if the `source` equal 6, then I run the function and then stop the loop. That part is good. The question is this. What goes in the `else`? I might have JSON with 15 or 20 different sources and I only need one of them to be 6 for the function to run. So, I need the function to continue to run until it finds a 6 for the `source` or it gets to the end of the array without finding a 6. If it doesn't ever find a 6, then I need to run a different function (say, `function2`).

How do I pull this all together?

Comment: Do not put an else statement. Add a variable source_find = false before your loop, set it to true if source == 6, and then after your foreach loop if source_find == true then function 2()

Comment: Can you explain the intended outcome a bit more clearly? It should run a *different* function for *any given* number? Do these work exclusively, e.g. if it runs `function1()` should it continue to run other functions, or stop?

Comment: You are missing a closing curly bracket in your 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a function like @Fortega function [findTheSix($response)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45570474/4369087), or you can just use the code directly like this :

```
$array = json_decode( $response, true );
$results = $array['data']['connections']; 

$six_exists = false;

foreach($results as $member) {
      if  ($member['source'] == 6){
         function1();//run this function
         $six_exists = true;
         break;
      }
 }

if(false === $six_exists) {
  function2();
}
```

or even better you can do it like this:

```
$array = json_decode($response, true);
if(in_array(6, array_column($array['data']['connections'], 'source'))) {
    function1();
} else {
    function2();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both worked great. Love the simple second one.

Answer (score 6):

you can put this code in a different function, and return when the 6 is found. If no 6 is found after looping, execute function2

```
function findTheSix($response){
    $array = json_decode( $response, true );
    $results = $array['data']['connections']; 
    foreach($results as $member) {
          if  ($member['source'] == 6){
            function1();//run this function
            return;
          }
     }
     function2();
}
```

Comment: So, the `return` says to run the `foreach` again until the condition is true or until there's nothing left in the array?

Comment: No, the return stops the (loop and) the rest of the function execution. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: @jonmrich please see my answer as I believe it will do what you want.

Comment: So, what tells the code to keep checking the array until it finds what it's looking for?

Comment: The foreach loops the elements of $member until it finds a 6.

Comment: @jonmrich I've posted a solution which uses `in_array` which checks the entire array in one go, so no need for looping.

Comment: For some reason, this always executes `function1` even if the condition isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better getting "source" into an array.

```
$source = array_column($array['data']['connections'], 'source'));
```

This should give you the values of "source", stored in an array called `$source` e.g.

```
[0 => 1, 1 => 6, ... ];
```

You could then do this type of thing. **This checks the whole array without the need for looping**:

```
if (in_array(6, $source)) {
    function1();
}
```

After this logic you could run any further functions you want, e.g.

```
if (in_array(6, $source)) {
    function1();
}
function2();
another_function();
```

`function1()` will execute if `6` is in the `$source` array. If not, `function1()` will not be executed.

Both `function2()` and `another_function()` will be executed irrespective of the `if` condition. If you want to change this so they're only executed if 6 is *not* in the `$source` array then use an `else` condition e.g.

```
if (in_array(6, $source)) {
    function1();
} else {
    function2();
    another_function();
}
```

Comment: This is giving me an error like: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'in_array' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in /test.php on line 75)". This is the line: `if in_array(6, $source) {`

Comment: Needed to be `if (in_array(6, $source)) {` However, this always is running the wrong function.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated it. It was missing `(` and closing `)` around the `in_array`. Works for me. How about you?

Comment: What's the "wrong" function? It will only run `function1()` if 6 is in the `$source` array. Try doing a `var_dump($source)` to make sure 6 is actually in there.

Comment: I don't think I'm pulling the right thing out of my array. Always runs the second function even when the condition is true. The problem is my array isn't as simple as what you show in your example.

Comment: Ok. I'm sure this method will work, it's a case of getting the right contents into the array. Is it just numbers (integers) that are coming from "source" in your json? That's what I can make out from your OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode( $response, true );
$results = $array['data']['connections']; 
$no_six = true;
foreach($results as $member) {
    if  ($member['source'] == 6) {
        function1();
        $no_six = false;
        break;
    }
}
if ($no_six) {
    function2();
}
```

- If you enconter a `['source']` that is equal to 6, `function1()` is called and the foreach is broken. `$no_six` is reset to false, since we have found one.
- No need for a `else` since the only thing you'll want to do if `['source']` isn't equal to 6 is to try again in the next iteration if there is one.
- If the foreach ends without the code in the if having been executed, it means that no `['source']` is equal to 6 and then `$no_six` is still equal to `false`. Using that info, you call `function2()`.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this, use contine with update in flag, it will traverse through complate array

```
$array = json_decode( $response, true );
$results = $array['data']['connections']; 
$no_six = 0;
foreach($results as $member) {
    if  ($member['source'] == 6) {
        function1();
        $no_six++;
        continue;
    }
}
if ($no_six>0) {
    function2();
}
```